# Which is more optimal? Join 2 tables Or Use an aditional column in a table

Tags: mysql, database, performance, left-join, tablecolumn

Table A1:

```
| id | name  | code | level |
|  1 | Anton | A111 |     2 |
|  2 | Berta | A112 |     5 |
```

Table B1:

```
| id | name  | code |
|  1 | Anton | A111 |
|  2 | Berta | A112 |
```

Table B2:

```
| id | code | level |
|  1 | A111 |     2 |
|  2 | A112 |     5 |
```

Which is more optimal?

use Table A1 (level column):

```
SELECT 'id,name' FROM A1 WHERE level=2;
```

OR

use Table B1 and Table B2 by Join (code column):

```
SELECT 'id,name' FROM B1 LEFT JOIN B2 ON B1.code=B2.code WHERE level=2;
```

*thank u.*

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself: is there a good reason for splitting the data across two tables besides performance?

Comment: Also databases are designed to handle raditional data model more effective it will also save diskspace in most cases and mistakes like capital letters issues as using `a111` instead off `A111`

Comment: You also need to keep in mind that UPDATE's will record lock in InnoDB.. When using @TimBiegeleisen method (normalized) would mean less record locking then on the denormalized tables.. If you want to update something like a code on denormalized  tables MySQL (innoDB) would record lock a great part of the table which is not good when the application or table needs to able handle lots off concurrent users (fast)

Comment: This question tends into the direction of "primarily opinion-based" and heavy database thoery which is way to broad.  For things like `ORDER BY table1.column, table2.column` a denormalized model with indexes are faster as MySQL is not able to optimize a `ORDER BY` on two separated tables well .. So then you would need to be simulating SQL 2003+ standard which is called a [Materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view)

Comment: For joining, the related column information are Normally fixed (Like the ID column)! @RaymondNijland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer to your question is that it is preferable to work with the two separate tables, rather than the joined/combined version `A1`.  The reason for this is the principle of *normalizaion*.  Consider the situation where a given name/code matches to *more* than one level, e.g. this `B2`:

```
| id | code | level |
|  1 | A111 |     2 |
|  1 | A111 |     3 |
|  1 | A111 |     4 |
|  2 | A112 |     5 |
```

Now joining would produce the following table:

```
| id | name  | code | level |
|  1 | Anton | A111 |     2 |
|  1 | Anton | A111 |     3 |
|  1 | Anton | A111 |     4 |
|  2 | Berta | A112 |     5 |
```

Note carefully that the above table contains *repeated* information.  We are replicating/storing the name and code three times.  In practice, if we use the two table version, we avoid this extra storage cost.

One possible justification for going with the `A1` table would be if you needed a lightning fast query to extract your information, and you wanted to avoid a join.  But, before you hit that case, you would first look into things like indices, which can usually speed things up enough before one resorts to denormalized table designs.

Comment: Storage is one thing, but that might not be the reason why you would go with the A model.  More likely, you would go with the A model because you need very high select performance.  In general though, you should always normalize your data in SQL.

Comment: @AminMaleki Method B (denormalized) would record lock most of the table if you update something., Method A (normalized) should give (much) better performance when dealing with lots of concurrent users

Answer (score 1):

First case (with one table) will work faster.
Also you have a varchar key in first case, SELECT queries will work slower than with integer keys.

If you have two tables that should be joined in SELECT queries, sometimes it could be good decision to store some fields from linked table in first table.

For example, you have a Users table with field town_id and a Town table with town_name.
It is faster to query user information and town name if town name is stored in the User table.

Comment: *"Second case (with one table) will work faster"* SELECT statements are not the only thing running on a table In fact most likely following this suggestion will slow the application/table when handling lots of concurrent users and UPDATES, see mine comment under the topicstarter question why..

Comment: So if I need to have one or two columns (with fixed data), the A model is a better option with a small amount of storage. Otherwise, Model B is a better option.